# How Can I take Screenshot using selenium Webdriver

Tags: webdriver

**Hello , please tell me how can i  take the screenshot of webpage by using selenium Webdriver in java ??**

Comment: Have you tried to Google? I've heard some people have found useful information there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @TESTasy sightly different question to that one and it doesnt contain an accepted answer.

I agree with dzieciou that this is the same as the one on stack so lifted it as an answer here to make it easier for people to find. (as this is Actually where it should be ;) )

Comment: Questions should not be cross posted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The following example is in Java:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

This answer has been lifted from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver) and written by Sergii Pozharov as the question could be useful to others within SQA.